# Large data submit changes

Tags: wcf, service, ria

I'm sorry that my english might not be appropriate.

My solution is Silverlight which uses WCF RIA service SP1.

I'm trying to submit change entity which have large string.

When it doesn't have large string, submit change's result is success.

But when it contains large string, submit change fails with this error.

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

I thought it is problem about timeout, so I tried below code. But it doesn't work.

```
            ChannelFactory<BatchContext.IBatchServiceContract> channel = ((WebDomainClient<BatchContext.IBatchServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory;
            channel.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
            channel.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
            channel.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
            channel.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
```

What should I do?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know that sometimes the exception you see may not be the real exception, expecially in WCF, so I suggest you use WCF Serivce Trace to find out the real exception.

And I think your problem may be familiar to this one: [wcf max message size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369132/wcf-max-message-size).